# ruby - git search by commit message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing an **[application](http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo)** for issue tracking in which I want to provide the ability to view revision information related to an issue. So, I need to search the git repository for commit with messages containing the issue key.

Currently, the only gem I found that could help me is [rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) but it doesn't provide this functionality. You can search only by the sha1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my idea would be to just embrace the powers of your command line.

it's super easy to do this in ruby and the git executable plays nice with calling into it:

```
`git log --oneline --grep=fail`.split("\n")
=> ["a9c6cf1 allow dashes in github names and show errors on failed validations, closes #54", "e140ed6 update friendly_id and fix failing spec", "871b06a remove failing test", "eff0c4b simplify failing test", "f72889f add production env, otherwise asset task will fail, wtf...", "daee196 first step of migrating to rails 3.1"]
```

this example searches for *fail* in the commit messages

Comment: Thank you @phoet , I'll wait in case anyone knows of a gem-integrated way otherwise I'll mark yours as the answer. I wanted to avoid the command line ;) I didn't know about the 'oneline' flag, cool.

Comment: why would you want to avoid the command line? that's the best thing about ruby! if you want to know more about `git log`, just type `git help log`. there are tons of useful flags and switches.

Comment: I wanted to have it in a more object-oriented way but it seems that I won't avoid it after all. Thank you for your help. Your answer wins ;)